# How to most efficiently get all filenames in a list that end with extensions matching those in a predefined array?

Tags: c#, list, search, optimization, findall

Specifically, I have a list of files and an array of compressed file extensions - I am trying to get all the zip files in a folder for later processing. **I reviewed a couple other StackOverflow answers but** they all involved having a series of "Contains" statements separates by or statements. What if I want to add a new extension during runtime? That just wasn't going to work for me.

```
string[] zipExts = new string[] { "zip", "tar.gz", "rar", "jar", "iso" };

// PseudoCode : Get a list of files
files = getfiles()

// Existing StackOverflow answers - their suggested way of doing things
var zips = files.FindAll(f => f.ToLower().Contains(zipExts[0].ToLower()) ||
    f.ToLower().Contains(zipExts[1].ToLower()) || 
    f.ToLower().Contains(zipExts[2].ToLower()) || 
    f.ToLower().Contains(zipExts[3].ToLower()) || 
    f.ToLower().Contains(zipExts[4].ToLower()));
```

What is the more efficient way to do this that doesn't require a series of or statements or a loop?

My own answer (the one I found myself then decided to document because I couldn't find it on StackOverflow) is an even cleaner version than the one to the question I am duplicating, because I *knew* there was a more concise way to do it (just didn't know how), so I didn't accept the other answers.

Comment: 1.5 minutes. You answered your own question in 1.5 minutes.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How to get only the files that match a certain extension?  If you are asking what the most optimal way of doing something is, that is **off topic** for Stack Overflow

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of thinking.

```
var zips = files.FindAll(f => zipExts.Any(z => f.EndsWith(z));
```

Wasn't able to answer my post while posting it (didn't see the button, stupidly assumed I just had to answer after posting my question), to document the knowledge (I found the answer before I started asking this question).